EAS build on Expo: production build not connecting to https nodejs
So I've been developing an android application on expo with socket.io to send messages to a NodeJS server and retrieve information. I'm very new to expo development for production so I might be doing a lot wrong unfortunately.
Problem: I have a NodeJS server that needs to connect to it. I've tried disabling the firewall on my laptop, connecting my laptop and phone to the same network. I have generated a free SSL certificate to use for my nodejs server but for some reason my production build running on my phone doesn't send any message to it.
Anybody have a clue as to how to resolve this? I've looked at a lot of posts and I've tried many suggestions but nothing works. I just want to run the apk on my phone and be able to connect to the NodeJS server running on my laptop, without having to connect my phone to android studio.
What works so far: So when I run the app on debug mode on my phone and I run the expo development server, I'm able to connect to my laptop over http, but not https. No idea how to set https for the front-end with this set up.
What I've tried so far but didn't work:

Running my server on https on my laptop and my production build on my phone
Using host name "0.0.0.0" in my server and my actual laptop IP to send a message from my expo app to the server
Downloading "expo-build-properties" as a plugin and setting "usesCleartextTraffic": true

